# How do I write many nested for-loops in a few lines of Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

**What I have:** I have the list `List123=[-13,3,12,1]` and the 2-by-4-matrix `Matrix123=numpy.zeros((2,4), dtype=Decimal)`.

**What I want:** I want to change all entries of the matrix to any entry of the list and then print it to the terminal. There are 4^(2*4)=65536 possible combinations. I want to print every combination.

**How I do it now:** Here is the my current code:

```
List123=[-13,3,12,1]

Matrix123=numpy.zeros((2,4), dtype=Decimal)

k=0
for k in List123:
    Matrix123[0,0]=k
    for k in List123:
        Matrix123[0,1]=k
        for k in List123:
            Matrix123[0,2]=k
            for k in List123:
                Matrix123[0,3]=k
                for k in List123:
                    Matrix123[1,0]=k
                    for k in List123:
                        Matrix123[1,1]=k
                        for k in List123:
                            Matrix123[1,2]=k
                            for k in List123:
                                Matrix123[1,3]=k
                                print Matrix123
                                print " "
```

**My question:** *What is a more compact way to write this in only a few lines of code?* I need to do the same for a 23-by-27 Matrix. That would mean that I have to write code for 23*27=621 for-loops manually, if I don't find a more compact way.

Comment: how about a for loop which iteratoes from 0 to 3 for the last slice of Matrix, and another for loop for the first index, ranging from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: You do realize that `4^(27*23) ~= 6.x10^373` and printing that many items will finish sometime around the heat death of the universe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

list123 = [-13, 3, 12, 1]

for matrix in itertools.product(list123, repeat=8):
  print matrix
```

It will output all the possible solution of length 8 with `-13, 3, 12 and 1`. `matrix` will be a tuple with 8 numbers, being the possible solutions.

If you need it to output the result in the real `numpy.matrix` form, you can create them on the fly (even though it will take more time).

```
import numpy as np

for prod in itertools.product(list123, repeat=8):
  print np.matrix([prod[:4], prod[4:]])
```

Or using [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to improve readability (Thanks to @MenglongLi)

```
for prod in itertools.product(list123, repeat=8):
  print np.reshape(prod, (2, 4))
```

It will gave you 65536 results as expected.

Comment: You really, really shouldn't use `numpy.matrix` anymore. Just use `np.array`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it due to performance issues? Can you provide a link or something about the topic?

Comment: No, more of a design consideration. Anyway, that's what [scipy recommends](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#short-answer). Essentially, `numpy.matrix` only exists for people coming from matlab to have something similar to the corresponding data-structure there. However, `numpy` and the `scipy` stack don't really have heavy support for it, and often, functions will return `numpy.ndarray`s regardless of if you input a `np.matrix`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga still, np.linalg.eigh return a np.matrix for the eigenvalue decomposition of an hermitian matrix, when it could return a 2D array. Why so?

Comment: @P.Camilleri I think a lot of the `linalg` functions do. Probably for historical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you to use itertools in python build-in tools:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

List123 = [-13, 3, 12, 1]

for i in product(List123, repeat=8):
    print(np.array(i).reshape(2, 4))
```

Here's a pure recursion function version:

```
import numpy as np

List123 = [-13, 3, 12, 1]

def dfs(depth=1, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if depth == 9:
        print(np.array(result).reshape(2, 4))
        return

    for i in List123:
        dfs(depth + 1, result + [i])

dfs()
```

In both way, you have 65536 results.

Comment: This is very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.meshgrid`:

```
def my_product(list, shape = (4,2)):
    r = np.product(shape)
    out = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*(List123,) * r))
    out = out.reshape(shape[::-1] + (-1,)).T
    for mat in list(out):
        print(mat)
```

Of course, if your `shape` is `(23,27)`, this will cause a `memerror` even if `len(list) = 2` as all those permutations would fill all the storage on earth a ridiculous number of times over, and printing them all would take until the heat death of the universe.